# Variables are undefined, even after declaration

Tags: php

My ONE,TWO, and THREE variables are undefined when I try and run the script even though it's defined in the global scope. My A,B, and C variables are considered defined though. At first I thought it was because I'm assigning constant values as keys, but I didn't find anything online that said I couldn't do that.

```
<?php class aClass
{


    const A = 1;
    const B = 2;
    const C = 3;

    const ONE = 1;
    const TWO = 2;
    const THREE = 3;
    public $arr = [];


    function __construct() {

        $this->createArray();

    }



    function createArray() {

        $this->arr[] = $this->A = [
            $this->ONE => 'one.',
            $this->TWO => 'two',
            $this->THREE => 'three'
            ];

        $this->arr[] = $this->B = [
            $this->ONE => 'one',
            $this->TWO => 'two',
            $this->THREE => 'three',
            ];

        $this->arr[] = $this->C = [
            $this->ONE => 'one',
            $this->TWO => 'two',
            $this->THREE => 'three',
            ];


    }
}


?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Can you include an example of what you want `$this->arr` to be after `createArray()` runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to change the constants in `createArray` from `$this=>` to `self::`, but that change alone should result in a syntax error:

```
$this->arr[] = self::A = [
    self::ONE => 'one.',
    self::TWO => 'two',
    self::THREE => 'three'
];
```

will get you a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

at this line:

```
$this->arr[] = self::A = [`
//                this ^ is the unexpected =
```

You mentioned using constant values as keys, which *is* what you're doing with

```
self::ONE => 'one.'
```

but is *not* what you're doing with

```
$this->arr[] = self::A = [ ...
```

With that line, you're not using `self::A` as a key, you're actually assigning the following array to `self::A` (which causes the *"unexpected '='"* error, because you can't assign things to constants), then assigning `self::A` to `$this->arr[]`.

If you want to use `self::A` as a key in `$this->arr`, you'll need to do it like this instead:

```
$this->arr[self::A] = [
    self::ONE => 'one.',
    self::TWO => 'two',
    self::THREE => 'three'
];
```

Answer (score 5):

You have defined constants and not attributes in your `aClass` class. You have to replace `$this->ONE` by `self::ONE`

Comment: I did this and my errors went away. However, I'm curious as to why I don't have to do this with my A,B,C variables, as they are constants themselves.

Comment: Because you are assigning theses variables, and not accessing it. Do you see the difference ?

Comment: A constant cannot be changed during runtime. If you do something like self::FOO = 'bar'; you will have an fatal error